# How to upgrade opkg packages from 2014.12 to 2018.12 when postinst script returns status 1 and opkg fails?

Tags: yocto

I have the image where packages are at 2014.12 level.

In /etc/opkg/base-feed.conf I replaced the URL for 2014.12 packages with the URL for 2018.12 packages.

'opkg update' updated the database.

But opkg fails to upgrade itself:

```
root@socfpga:~# opkg upgrade opkg
Configuring util-linux-readprofile.
update-alternatives: Error: cannot register alternative readprofile to /sbin/readprofile since it is already registered to /usr/sbin/readprofile
Collected errors:
 * pkg_run_script: package "util-linux-readprofile" postinst script returned status 1.
 * opkg_configure: util-linux-readprofile.postinst returned 1.
```

What do I do now? How do I upgrade the packages?

Comment: First, "2014.12" and "2018.12" aren't useful information on their own: are they version numbers of an OS from your vendor or just a versioning scheme you use for your distro/image?

Comment: Second, just replacing a package feed with another can not guarantee that devices are able to upgrade -- especially over a four year period that your version numbers suggest. If your packages come from an operating system vendor you should ask them what the supported upgrade path is. If you're constructing the upgrade yourself... well, you will probably have to debug and fix any upgrade issues in the recipes with patches.

Comment: Your specific case is probably related to this change http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/commit/meta/recipes-core/util-linux?id=43424eb3c8bf03a2f9ec331b78dd4040dd39eacd and probably requires adding a update-alternatives call to a pre/post install script to remove the old alternative registration ...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: 2014.12 and 2018.12 are Yocto-project version numbers.

Comment: I don't mean to nitpick but those are not yocto versions. See https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Releases for release names and versions numbers